# Tensorflow throws error when I try to subtract to idententical tensors in size, and says that they are different in size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm building a little something in tensor 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRQc7.png)'s a picture of the code so that you will be able to see the debugger comment.

As you can see the compiler claim that encrypted and encryted2 ARE the same size.
but the error I'm getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
>    packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 560, in merge_with
>       new_dims.append(dim.merge_with(other[i]))
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 135, in merge_with
>       self.assert_is_compatible_with(other)
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 108, in assert_is_compatible_with
>       % (self, other))
>   ValueError: Dimensions 40 and 20 are not compatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/user-pc/PycharmProjects/untitled12/Conv2.py", line 275, in 
>       train_neural_network(x, img1, img2)
>     File "C:/Users/user-pc/PycharmProjects/untitled12/Conv2.py", line 233, in train_neural_network
>       optimizer1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost1)
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
>       grad_loss=grad_loss)
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\optimizer.py", line 386, in compute_gradients
>       colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 580, in gradients
>       in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 413, in set_shape
>       self._shape = self._shape.merge_with(shape)
>     File "C:\Users\user-pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 564, in merge_with
>       (self, other))
>   ValueError: Shapes (?, 40, 40, 1) and (?, 20, 20, 1) are not compatible

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: Please, share the code in an appropriate way! the link you added is for an image file

Comment: That's so you can see that the debugger does indicate that the two Tensors are the same size

Comment: In my opinion, it is still hard to copy paste the code from your image to reproduce.  Please add it if you want to have a better chance of getting an answer

Answer (score 0):

The model shapes at compile time mean nothing. The actual shapes depend on the input you pass when you run the session.

Assuming convolutional_neural_network is a series of convolutions/maxpools (basically, no fully connected layers), the output shape would depend on the input shape. It's possible you're feeding different input shapes to the two convolutional_neural_network calls and hence getting tensors of different shapes.